# tfs code review - how to comment on deleted lines?

Tags: tfs

When code is added or modified - I can usek CTRL+SHIFT+K to add comment, 
but when code line is deleted - then there is no place to hook for comments.

> Is there a way to add comments like "why this was deleted?"?

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - found this when finishing creating my question :-)

**right click on file and select add file comment.**

[image: screenshot]